# Error getting response from a web service Non-default namespace can not map to empty URI

Tags: java, webservice-client, axis

I'm trying to make a java webservice client. It's a very simple service that receives a String and return another String. I'm testing the service with soapUI and works perfectly but when I try to code it in java it fails.

Here is the code I'm using to call the service

```
    QName QNAME_TYPE_STRING = new QName(nameSpaceURI,"string");
    Service service = new Service();
    Call call = (Call) service.createCall();
    call.setTargetEndpointAddress(new java.net.URL(endpoint));
    call.setOperationName(new QName(nameSpaceURI, webServiceMethod));
    call.addParameter("buil:arg0", XMLType.XSD_STRING, ParameterMode.IN);
    call.setReturnType(QNAME_TYPE_STRING, String.class);
    String ret = (String) call.invoke(new Object[]{"PARAMETER VALUE"});
```

The `endPoint` variable points correctly to the URL of the service, and:

```
nameSpaceURI = "http://build.response.service/";
webServiceMethod = "buildResponse";
```

The thing is that the webService gets the parameter correctly but something happens on the response:

```
Caused by: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxParsingException: Non-default namespace can not map to
empty URI (as per Namespace 1.0 # 2) in XML 1.0 documents
at javax.xml.stream.SerializableLocation@6fee8ce6
```

This is a sample of my request on soapUI

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:buil="http://build.response.service/">
    <soapenv:Header/>
        <soapenv:Body>
            <buil:buildResponse>
                <buil:arg0>PARAMETER VALUE</buil:arg0>
            </buil:buildResponse>
        </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

And this is a sample of the response on soapUI

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Body>
        <ns1:buildResponse xmlns:ns1="http://build.response.service/">
            <return xmlns="http://build.response.service/">
                RESPONSE1,RESPONSE2,RESPONSE3
            </return>
        </ns1:buildResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

¿Ideas? I think this has something to do with the response, but I'm really a novice with webServices (I know... I know... the 21th century...).

Some more information: I'm not authorized to use wsdl2java nor publish the wsdl of the service (it's autogenerated anyway, I have nothing to do with it and it won't change). Sorry about this, I hope can help me despite this limitations.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

God... it was so simple, made this little change on the call parameters:

```
call.addParameter(new QName(nameSpaceURI, "buil:arg0"),XMLType.XSD_STRING,ParameterMode.IN);
call.addParameter(new QName(nameSpaceURI, "return"), XMLType.XSD_STRING, ParameterMode.OUT);
```

Now it works like a charm, hope this helps someone.